# Why hasAuthInKeychain() not always returns true while signing in a user with his google account to my Swift app?

Tags: ios, swift, appdelegate, google-signin

I'm following official google sign in tutorial from here https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/start?ver=swift and I already implemented it, however I still face some basic errors. First of all - google suggest to do all that stuff in `AppDelegate`. So I put there all the necessary methods:

```
func application(application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

        // Initialize sign-in
        var configureError: NSError?
        GGLContext.sharedInstance().configureWithError(&configureError)
        assert(configureError == nil, "Error configuring Google services: \(configureError)")

        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate = self

        return true
}
```

and the other function - since I'm using the backend server to authorize the user:

```
func signIn(signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInForUser user: GIDGoogleUser!,
    withError error: NSError!) {
        if (error != nil) {
            print("Looks like we have a sign in error: \(error)")
        }else {
            let tokenAsAParam = [
                "id_token":user.authentication.idToken
            ]

            NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("ToggleAuthUINotification", object: nil, userInfo: ["statusText" : "Signed in user \(user)"])
            Alamofire.request(.POST, "http://mywebservice", parameters: tokenAsAParam)
                .response { (request, response, data, error) in
                    if(error != nil){
                        print("error during signing in with google= \(error)")
                        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signOut()
                    }else{

                        let sb = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
                        if let tabBarVC = sb.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("TabController") as? TabController {
                            self.window!.rootViewController = tabBarVC

                        }

                    }
            }
            }
}
```

All that happens in `AppDelegate.swift`. But from there I'm not able to show user the popup to wait for the response from my webservice (before moving the user from `ViewController` to the main `TabController`), so so far the use case scenario is as follows:

1) user opens app and clicks sign in with google

2) user puts google credentials, clicks ok

3) user comes back to the page from point no. 1 (with google sign in button visible)

4) the app makes a call to webservice and in case of positive result it transfers user to the main TabController - when the internet connection is poor this takes some time and then user is confused because he is stuck for some time on the screen from point 1 and 3.

I would like to show some kind of indicator that the signing in process takes some time and user should wait. So in the code of ViewController I did:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {

GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().uiDelegate = self

if(GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().hasAuthInKeychain()){
        loadingIndicator.startAnimating()
        print("we are here")
        someView.hidden = false //this is my view that contains "please wait sign"
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signInSilently()
    }else{
        print("we are there")
        someView.hidden = true
    }
```

It almost works, but in some scenarios the `GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().hasAuthInKeychain()` has a value `false` even though the user is signed in.

For example:

when user turns the app and is already signed in - then he sees my `please wait` popup and after a short while he is redirected to the TabController. 
But when user is not signed in and clicks the google button `sign in with google` then - after putting credentials - the app comes back to my view controller with that button and I can see in the console: `we are there` - still, after a short while user goes to TabController, so seems like even though the `GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().hasAuthInKeychain()` got false - he was still able to log in. I think it might be a bug, but at this point I don't know yet. Do you know what might be wrong over here? Or maybe can you suggest me how to present a `please wait` message in that kind of scenario?

==========EDIT 
I just found out this - https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/issues/27 it looks related to my problem, maybe someone from you guys had seen it before?

Comment: did you get any solution to the hasAuthInKeychain() returning false sometimes?